# Tuple with Variadic Templates compile error

Tags: c++11, templates, c++14, variadic-templates, variadic

I am trying to learn variadic templates with a self made tuple implementation. 
Could someone please explain to me why the following results in a compile error ?

```
namespace my
{
  // Template definition
  template <typename... Ts> struct tuple;

  template <typename T, typename... Ts>
  struct tuple<T, Ts...> : public tuple<Ts...>
  {
    tuple(T t, Ts... ts) : tuple<Ts...>(ts...), mVal(t) {}
    T mVal;
  };

  template <typename T>
  struct tuple<T>
  {
    tuple(T t) : mVal(t) {}
    T mVal;
  };


  // GetType at an index
  template <size_t i, typename... Ts> struct GetType {};

  template <size_t i, typename T, typename... Ts> 
  struct GetType<i, tuple<T,Ts...> > 
  {
    using Type = typename GetType<i-1, tuple<Ts...> >::Type;
  };

  template <typename T, typename... Ts>
  struct GetType<0, tuple<T,Ts...> >
  {
    using Type = T;
  };


  template <size_t i, typename... Ts>
  typename GetType<i,tuple<Ts...> >::Type Get(tuple<Ts...>& t);

  template <size_t i, typename T, typename... Ts>
  typename GetType<i,tuple<T,Ts...> >::Type Get(tuple<T,Ts...>& t)
  {
    return Get<i-1, tuple<Ts...> >(t);
  }

  template <typename T, typename... Ts>
  typename GetType<0,tuple<T,Ts...> >::Type Get(tuple<T,Ts...>& t)
  {
    return (static_cast<tuple<T, Ts...> >(t)).mVal;
  }  
}

int main()
{
  using myTuple = my::tuple<int, std::string, double, char>;

  // The following lines compile fine ....
  my::GetType<0,myTuple>::Type s0 = 437;
  my::GetType<1,myTuple>::Type s1 = std::string("Test string");
  my::GetType<2,myTuple>::Type s2 = 299.3243;
  my::GetType<3,myTuple>::Type s3 = 'Z';
  std::cout << s0 << " - " << s1 << " - " << s2 << " - " << s3 << std::endl;

  myTuple t(437, "This is the actual tuple string", 299.3243, '§');
  // This line does not compile !!! 
  int v = my::Get<0>(t);

  return 0;
}
```

My Intention is that the indicated line will use the specialization but looking at the compile error it is obvious that the specialization for `value=0` is not being used. Your help is very appreciated.

Thank you for your time ..

```
c:\users\praka\workspace\cpp\cpp-tests\recipes\tuple\tuple.h(27): error C2039: 'Type': is not a member of 'my::GetType<18446744073709551614,my::tuple<>>'
c:\users\praka\workspace\cpp\cpp-tests\recipes\tuple\tuple.h(27): note: see declaration of 'my::GetType<18446744073709551614,my::tuple<>>'
c:\users\praka\workspace\cpp\cpp-tests\recipes\tuple\tuple.h(43): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'my::GetType<18446744073709551615,my::tuple<my::tuple<std::string,double,char>>>' being compiled
..\test.cpp(15): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'int my::Get<0,int,std::string,double,char>(my::tuple<int,std::string,double,char> &)' being compiled
c:\users\praka\workspace\cpp\cpp-tests\recipes\tuple\tuple.h(27): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'Type'
c:\users\praka\workspace\cpp\cpp-tests\recipes\tuple\tuple.h(27): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
c:\users\praka\workspace\cpp\cpp-tests\recipes\tuple\tuple.h(43): error C2672: 'Get': no matching overloaded function found
c:\users\praka\workspace\cpp\cpp-tests\recipes\tuple\tuple.h(43): error C2770: invalid explicit template argument(s) for 'GetType<i,my::tuple<Ts...>>::Type my::Get(my::tuple<Ts...> &)'
c:\users\praka\workspace\cpp\cpp-tests\recipes\tuple\tuple.h(38): note: see declaration of 'my::Get'
```

Comment: There is no specialization of `Get` in your code. Moreover, you cannot partially specialize a function. You can wrap it by a `struct` and make it a `static` member function instead.

Comment: Thanks for this. I read about it in the book of Andrei Alexandrescu, but forgot miserably. I hope not amymore ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off Topic Introductory Suggestion: if you want to play with language to recreate your version of a standard tool (`std::tuple`, in this case), please, avoid to give the same names to your structs, classes, functions, types...

This can avoid a lot of strong headaches.

End of suggestion.

As observed by Daniel Langr, there isn't partial specialization for template functions.

So it's difficult to obtain what you want only with functions.

But structs/classes can partial specialize, so I suggest a `getH` helper `struct` written as follows

```
  template <std::size_t I, typename T, typename ... Ts>
  struct getH
   {
     static typename GetType<I, tuple<T, Ts...>>::Type
        func (tuple<T, Ts...> const & t)
      { return getH<I-1U, Ts...>::func(t); }
   };

  template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
  struct getH<0U, T, Ts...>
   {
     static T func (tuple<T, Ts...> const & t)
      { return t.mVal; }
   };
```

So your `Get` can be written

```
  template <std::size_t I, typename ... Ts>
  typename GetType<I, tuple<Ts...>>::Type Get(tuple<Ts...> const & t)
   { return getH<I, Ts...>::func(t); };
```

If you can use C++14, the return types can be simplified in `auto` instead `typename GetType<I, tuple<T, Ts...>>::Type`.

I observe that in your code you've used `static_cast` when isn't needed

You've used it in `Get<0>`

```
  template <typename T, typename... Ts>
  typename GetType<0,tuple<T,Ts...> >::Type Get(tuple<T,Ts...>& t)
  {
    return (static_cast<tuple<T, Ts...> >(t)).mVal;
  }
```

when `mVal` is of type `T` (aka `typename GetType<0,tuple<T,Ts...> >::Type`)

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer and correcting the uselessness of the static_cast. I think i will go with wrapping the functions in structs.